# Does my code leak memory (python)?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

```
    links_list = char.getLinks(words)
    for source_url in links_list:
        try:
            print 'Downloading URL: ' + source_url
            urldict = hash_url(source_url)
            source_url_short = urldict['url_short']
            source_url_hash = urldict['url_short_hash']
            if Url.objects.filter(source_url_short = source_url_short).count() == 0:
                    try:
                        htmlSource = getSource(source_url)
                    except:
                        htmlSource = '-'
                        print '\thtmlSource got an error...'
                new_u = Url(source_url = source_url, source_url_short = source_url_short, source_url_hash = source_url_hash, html = htmlSource)
                new_u.save()
                time.sleep(3)
            else:
                print '\tAlready in database'
        except:
            print '\tError with downloading URL..'
            time.sleep(3)
            pass


def getSource(theurl, unicode = 1, moved = 0):
    if moved == 1:
        theurl = urllib2.urlopen(theurl).geturl()
    urlReq = urllib2.Request(theurl)
    urlReq.add_header('User-Agent',random.choice(agents))
    urlResponse = urllib2.urlopen(urlReq)
    htmlSource = urlResponse.read()
    htmlSource =  htmlSource.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
    return htmlSource
```

basically what this code does is...it takes a list of URLs and downloads them, saves them to a DB. That's all.

Comment: is there a reason you think your code leaks memory?

Comment: Any error happens? or taking too much time? This is abit strange though, `htmlSource.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')`, its decode from utf8 and encode back to utf8 at the same time.

Comment: No errors happen. However, my script randomly gets "killed".  And some people before suggested that it was a memory-leak , causing my memory to be overloaded.

Comment: if you are on some shared web hosting, crawling websites are not very good idea, because sometimes, its take long time, even sometime no repsonse at all, for that case, your script stay in memory, and some hosting might put automatic killing scripts to protect other customers.

Comment: A memory leak is when you allocate memory and lose the address in one way or another and won't free the allocation. You are doing none of this. Your script is being randomly killed most un-handled probably because of an exception. Improve the debugging on the script and try to reproduce the problem to see why it is getting killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your process uses too much memory and the server (perhaps shared host) just kills it because you exhaust your memory quota.

here you use a call that may eat up a lot of memory:

```
links_list = char.getLinks(words)
for source_url in links_list:
     ...
```

Looks like you might be building a whole list in memory and then work with items. Instead it might be better to use iterator, where objects are retrieved one at at time. But this is a guess because it's hard to tell from your code what char.getLinks does

if you are using Django in debug mode, then memory usage will go up, as Mark suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in Django, make sure DEBUG is False, otherwise it will cache every query.

[See FAQ](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check is to go to the task manager (on Windows - or equivalent on other platforms) and check the memory requirements of the Python process. If it stays constant, there are no memory leaks. If not, you have a memory leak somewhere and you will need to debug

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should get a job server such as [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) and think about doing just one at a time.

The job server will requeue the ones that fail, allowing the rest to complete.  You can also run more than one client concurrently should you need to (even on more than one machine).

Simpler design, easier to understand and test, more fault tolerant, retryable, more scalable, etc...